# result object returned as undefined when assigned a value

Tags: node.js

I am creating a results object to return a boolean and a string. it is not being reassigned within the if statement. The rest of the code is working correctly and the password gets updated or the right error message is output to the console

i've tried leaving result undefined before the try catch.

```
async function passwordUpdate(password, currentPassword, newPwd, email) {
  let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPwd, 10);
  let result  = { success: false , message: ' '};

  try {
    bcrypt.compare(currentPassword, password, async function (err, res) {
      if (res) {
        let updateResult = await updatePwd(hashedPassword, email);
        if (updateResult) {
         result = { success: true , message: 'Password was updated successfully.'}; 
        }
        else {
          logger.info('Password was not updated successfully.');
        }
      } else {
        logger.error('Passwords do not match');
        result= { success: false , message: 'Your current password was entered incorrectly'};

        logger.error(result.message);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    result= { success: false , message: 'Failed to compare passwords'}
  }
  logger.error('result ', result.message);
  return result;
}
```

code is being called by this method

```
app.post('/passwordUpdate', async (req, res) => {
  let pwd = req.body.password;
  let cpwd = req.body.currentPwd;
  let newPwd = req.body.newPwd;
  let email = req.body.email;

  try {
    let result = await usersModel.passwordUpdate(pwd, cpwd, newPwd, email);
    console.log(result, result.success, result.message);
    if (result.success) {
      res.status(200).json({error: result.message});
    }
    else {
      res.status(404).json({error: result.message});
    }
  } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
  }
});
```

logger.error(result.message); this line within the else statement is outputting the message as expected but
logger.error('result ', result.message); after the try/catch is outputting a blank message for result.message

Comment: Can you add the code that you are calling this method

Comment: edited the original question to include the calling code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing this:

```
let result = await usersModel.passwordUpdate(pwd, cpwd, newPwd, email);
```

The `passwordUpdate` function is resolving the promise based on what is in that function's "top level". This means that the callback function of `bcrypt.compare` doesn't affect the return of `passwordUpdate` which is why you're not seeing the result you're looking for.

What you can do is wrap the entire thing in a promise and call the `resolve`/`reject` inside the `bcrypt.compare` function.

```
async function passwordUpdate(password, currentPassword, newPwd, email) {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPwd, 10)

    try {
      bcrypt.compare(currentPassword, password, async function(err, res) {
        if (res) {
          let updateResult = await updatePwd(hashedPassword, email)
          if (updateResult) {
            resolve({
              success: true,
              message: 'Password was updated successfully.',
            })
          } else {
            reject({
              success: false,
              message: 'Password was not updated successfully.',
            })
          }
        } else {
          reject({
            success: false,
            message: 'Your current password was entered incorrectly',
          })
        }
      })
    } catch (error) {
      reject({ success: false, message: 'Failed to compare passwords' })
    }
  })
}
```

You'll also notice I removed the logging, you can put these back if you wish but since this is a promise you can log your errors more centrally from the caller in the `.then` and `.catch` or `try`/`catch` if you're using `async`/`await`.

Also may I suggest that since you'll be able to determine whether it's an error or not based on the `resolve` and `reject`, that you can remove the `success` from the result and only return a string, it'll make the code cleaner:

```
async function passwordUpdate(password, currentPassword, newPwd, email) {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPwd, 10)

    try {
      bcrypt.compare(currentPassword, password, async function(err, res) {
        if (res) {
          const updateResult = await updatePwd(hashedPassword, email)

          if (updateResult) {
            resolve('Password was updated successfully.')
          } else {
            reject('Password was not updated successfully.')
          }
        } else {
          reject('Your current password was entered incorrectly')
        }
      })
    } catch (error) {
      reject('Failed to compare passwords')
    }
  })
}
```

***PS: I didn't test the code pasted above, I only modified your code to better explain it.***